# I have a maven project which keep on throwing exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java

JNA: Callback za.co.eoh.ab.fbgrabber.swing.FPGrabber$9@ee7040 threw the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: za/co/ideco/wsqcodec/WSQIdecoException
    at za.co.eoh.ab.fbgrabber.swing.FPGrabber.showImage(FPGrabber.java:675)
    at za.co.eoh.ab.fbgrabber.swing.FPGrabber.resultImageCallback(FPGrabber.java:759)
    at za.co.eoh.ab.fbgrabber.swing.FPGrabber.access$800(FPGrabber.java:69)
    at za.co.eoh.ab.fbgrabber.swing.FPGrabber$9.invoke(FPGrabber.java:748)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback(CallbackReference.java:485)
    at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback(CallbackReference.java:515)
```